# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined Sending to specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that announces events at a specific time/date.
Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!');
 client.channels.cache.get('id').send('test')
});
while (true){
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours();
  var day = today.getDay();
  if (day == 5) {
    if (time == 0) {
      client.channels.cache.get('id').send('event1');
    }
  }
  if (day = 3) {
    if (time = 15) {
      client.channels.cache.get('id').send('event2')
    }
  }
}

client.login('token');
```

(Obviously I've replaced a few parts)
The error message is:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

And it only comes up at event2. It also doesn't send the message "test".

Comment: This error is thrown because the result of `cache.get('id')` is undefined.

Comment: Why would it only throw it after event2?

Comment: Try to `console.log(client.channels)` to see what's the output and you can troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues in your code. You're performing an assignment on your day and time here:

### Issue 1 - assignment

```
if (day = 3) {
  if (time = 15) {
    client.channels.cache.get('id').send('event2')
  }
}
```

What this code means is if javascript managed to successfully set `day` to be `3` (which it will), and if javascript managed to successfully set `time` to be `15`, again (which it also will), then it should execute `client.channels.cache.get('id').send('event2')`.

You need to use double or triple equals to check for equality.

This is the reason your `client.channels.cache.get('id').send('event2')` is throwing an error first. It's the first such line that's actually being run.

### Issue 2 - getting a channel by id

You're using `client.channels.cache.get('id')` to try and get the channel you  want to broadcast to.

`'id'` is just a placeholder, and needs to be replaced with the channel id.

### Issue 3 - directly accessing the cache

There's not really a reason to directly access the cache, you should use `client.channels.fetch('id')` - again, replace id with the channel id.

It will automatically access the cache or query the server, depending on which is more appropriate.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!');
 client.channels.fetch('id').send('test')
});
while (true){
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours();
  var day = today.getDay();
  if (day == 5) {
    if (time == 0) {
      client.channels.fetch('id').send('event1');
    }
  }
  if (day == 3) {
    if (time == 15) {
      client.channels.fetch('id').send('event2')
    }
  }
}

client.login('token');
```

### Extras for experts

Your code has some other issues (the `while(true)` loop will keep looping even though it's only checking the time 99.9% of the time). I recommend searching for other patterns people have used to implement time-based tasks with discord.js.

Comment: Now it's throwing TypeError: client.channels.fetch(...).send is not a function (Thank you for the other things though!)

Comment: So, there's a pretty huge area for errors to break your code. Your `client.channels.fetch('id').send()` calls are called outside a check to see whether the client's successfully logged in. If you're forcing one of your conditionals to be truthy, the code will be trying to send a message before the client has logged in.